# How to split parallel corpora while keeping alignment?

Tags: python, pandas, unix, scikit-learn, dataset

I have two text files containing parallel text in two languages (potentially millions of lines).  I am trying to generate random train/validate/test files from that single file, as `train_test_split` does in `sklearn`.  However when I try to import it into pandas using `read_csv` I get errors from many of the lines because of erroneous data in there and it would be way too much work to try and fix the broken lines.  If I try and set the `error_bad_lines=false` then it will skip some lines in one of the files and possibly not the other which would ruin the alignment.  If I split it manually using unix `split` it works fine for my needs though so I'm not concerned with cleaning it, but the data that is returned is not random.
How should I go about splitting this dataset into train/validate/test sets?
I'm using python but I can also use linux commands if that would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use the `shuf` command on the file with the `random-source` parameter, like this `shuf tgt-full.txt -o tgt-fullshuf.txt --random-source=tgt-full.txt`.